# Compare Two arrays - return unmatched array items

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have 2 arrays, like below.

```
$arr1=

array:8 [▼
  0 => array:18 [▼

    "c_id" => 19
    "datetime" => "2017-01-20 21:48:16"
    "aparty" => "8801911255104"
    "bparty" => "8801961185321"
    "call_duration" => "0"
    "usage_type" => "SMSMT"
    "lac" => "532"
    "cell" => "13174"
    "imei" => "357328068823480"
    "imsi" => "470037500180672"
    "network_type" => "Undefined"
  ]
  1 => array:18 [▶]
  2 => array:18 [▶]
  3 => array:18 [▶]
  4 => array:18 [▶]
  5 => array:18 [▶]
  6 => array:18 [▶]
  7 => array:18 [▶]
]


$arr2= = [
          'c_id' => '1',
          'datetime' =>'2017-01-20 21:48:16' ,
          'aparty' => '8801911255104',
          'bparty' =>'8801911255104',
          'call_duration' => '999',
          'usage_type' =>'MC',
          'lac' => '555',
          'cell' => '99',
          'imei' => '6y8887766',
          'imsi' => '6y8887766',
          'network_type' =>'Undefined'
  ];
```

Now I want to compare second array with first array . logic is if `$arr2` not exist in $arr1 then insert into database.if exist then nothing insert

i cant understand , i am trying to use this code but not work

```
foreach($arr1 as $k=>$v){
    $dif = abs($arr1[$k] - $arr2[$k]);
    if($dif) return false else return true;
}
```

Comment: Looking for array_diff function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Your code doesn't manipulate arrays at all. It certainly doesn't even try to find items in `arr2` that aren;t in `arr1`.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged the question as `laravel` and that this is about inserting into the database, so also assuming Eqloeunt.

You can leverage the following Eloquent function:

```
$model = App\YourModel::firstOrCreate($arr2);
```

Which saves messing with the array directly.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#inserts